# IPv6 Virtual Network in Linux

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ipv6

I'm going to do a project based on IPv6 Network. So I need to create a IPv6 Virtual Network in my Linux OS (I use Ubuntu). Also I need to create some virtual hosts in my virtual network and setup static IPs (local IPs) for each and every host. And I need to run a terminal on each virtual host.

Can I setup that kind of an environment on my Linux OS? Please give me some help to do this.

Comment: If you don't need to route the traffic, you can use the auto-configured, link-local addresses.

Answer (score 1):

it's almost the same thing as configuring ipv4 interface/virtual interface, 
Here is a sample of what you could put into /etc/network/interfaces file

```
iface eth0:1 inet6 static
pre-up modprobe ipv6
address youripv6address
netmask yournetmask
gateway yourgateway
```